# R package doesn't install from github

Tags: r, github, package

I am using RStudio with R (Version 4.0.2) and I am trying to install this climate package from github: https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/climate4R
when I type: `install_github("SantanderMetGroup/climate4R")`

```
I get this error:
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`SantanderMetGroup`) and repo name (`climate4R`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

I also downloaded the zipped package and tried to manually install the package within rstudio and got this error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/...../Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'climate4R-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Why is it not installing? I have downloaded packages from github before with no problems.

UPDATED HERE:
I had already tried what is suggested below, but it also didn't work. I wanted to check first if I had missed something and it was possible to download the package all at once. When I input this:

```
library(devtools)
install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java",
                   "SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG",
                   "SantanderMetGroup/loadeR",
                   "SantanderMetGroup/transformeR",
                   "SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR",
                   "SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCAqAGF\remotes39b87d2f4f9\SantanderMetGroup-loadeR.java-88da23e/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'loadeR.java':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'loadeR.java_1.1.1.tar.gz'
   

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'loadeR.java' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: fun(libname, pkgname)   error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry Error: package 'rJava' could not be loaded Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'loadeR.java'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0/loadeR.java' Error: Failed to install 'loadeR.java' from GitHub:   (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCAqAGF/file39b86ae96acb/loadeR.java_1.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Did you read the README at the repo? "climate4R is formed by the following four core packages (all in GitHub): loadeR , transformeR, downscaleR and visualizeR. These packages are fully documented in the corresponding GitHub wikis." So this is NOT a package, but points you to them

Comment: As @HongOoi said, there is no `climate4R` package there.  You should follow the installation instructions further down in the `README`.

Comment: @Steffen Moritz I read the 'readme' file. But I was getting errors with everything I tried, so I started with the first two here in my question. I have updated it to show the error I got when I used the code provided on the webpage.

Comment: Install Java 123

Comment: @HongOoi What is Java 123? I can't find it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install this package, I had to install this:JDK 13
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk13-downloads.html

This allowed each of the packages to be installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the GitHub Repo is not an  R package by itself.

Here from their GitHub [Readme](https://github.com/SantanderMetGroup/climate4R) how to install their collection of packages that form the `climate4R` toolset.

```
library(devtools)
install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java",
             "SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG",
             "SantanderMetGroup/loadeR",
             "SantanderMetGroup/transformeR",
             "SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR",
             "SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR"))
```